# Top Questions of the Week #11

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 11 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 5):

We all know @nhinkle makes the most good looking posts of us all. Don't believe me?

### Check out this Excel question: [Excel 2007 - Custom Y-axis values](https://superuser.com/q/268868/1548)

[image]

So I guess it's time for some lessons on how to use Excel from @nhinkle!

Comment: You're welcome to post this as the QOTW for this week, though I don't have time at the moment to write a full-blown high-quality post about Excel. I will eventually though, maybe even as a series, so feel free to mention that there will be more excel posts coming.